# Have ANT open a Terminal window and run command?

Tags: eclipse, ant, terminal, flash-builder

I have a command / executable in ANT that opens and then closes immediately.

```
    <exec executable="${FLEX_HOME}/bin/fdb" spawn="false" >
        <arg line="run '${application}'"/>
    </exec>
```

I'm guessing it has to be run with Terminal (because I double clicked on it and terminal is what opened)? I'm not that familiar with this type of program? Is there a way I can keep this program open and / or send commands to it with ANT?

**More context**
The file above, "fdb" is a reference to the Flash Player Debugger. After compiling an application I am trying to use fdb to debug the application and get the trace statements. Here is more information on FD, http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ffb.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62063-7ff3.

Flash Builder / Eclipse has a console that would be better to debug and trace with if output could be made through that but that may be another question.

Comment: Can you expand on your use case a bit ?  Ant is normally used to automate build and test processes that can run headlessly, so you wouldn't need to interact with it.

Answer (score 1):

Can't help with main part of your question but using FBs built-in ANT auto sends output to the FB console window.

You should be able to open the ANT view via WINDOW > SHOW VIEW > OTHER... then pick ANT